# I would like my bot to send a dm to the person who and ban

Tags: discord, discord.js, bots

I made my bot etc but I would like to make it so that the bot sends a dm when it ban a person I do not find it has been 3 hours that I search but without success

```js
exports.run = (client, message, args) => {
    if (message.member.hasPermission('BAN_MEMBERS')) {
        const user = message.mentions.users.first();
        let reason = args.slice(1).join(' ');
        if (!reason) reason = "No reason provided";
        if (user) {
            const member = message.guild.member(user);
            user.send("You we're banned from **__" + message.guild.name + "__** for **__" + reason + "__**")
                .catch(() => message.reply("Unable to send message to user"))
                .then(() => member.ban({
                    reason: "BANNED!"
                }))
                .catch(err => {
                    message.reply('I was unable to ban the member');
                    console.error(err);
                });
            if (member) {
                member
                    .ban({})
                    .then(() => {
                        message.reply(`Successfully banned **__${user.tag}__** for **__${reason}__**`);
                    })
                    .catch(err => {
                        message.reply('I was unable to ban the member');
                        console.error(err);
                    });
            } else {
                message.reply("That user isn't in this guild!");
            }
        } else {
            message.reply("You didn't mention the user to ban!");
        }
    } else {
        message.reply('you don\'t have permission to ban members!')
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a few flaws here.

Firstly, `message.guild.member()` is not a method. You should instead use `message.mentions.members.first();` instead of `message.mentions.users.first()`, then access the `User` object via `GuildMember.user` (in your case, `user.user`, unless you rename the variable) if you need to. You could use `guild.members.fetch()` but this is much easier.

Secondly, you try to message, if you can't you don't bother banning. Which means if a user blocks your bot, they can prevent getting banned by it. So to fix this, with your current code, just do

```js
user.send("message")
.catch(err => {
    message.reply("User could not be messaged");
});
user.ban( {reason: "BANNED!"} )
.catch(err => {
    message.reply("User could not be banned");
});
```

If it continues to error after this, please respond with the error your receive.